# how to import more than one csv file in aws s3 into redshift with aws glue

Tags: amazon-redshift, aws-glue

i want to join more than one csv file from aws s3 and move the file into redshift using aws glue

i have tried move a single file to redshift it is working, I have seen solutions via pyspark, can I do the same via gui without using coding

Comment: all the files have same schema and are placed in the same s3 location?

Comment: Why not use copy command in Redshift? It is faster.